# gitolite: How to prevent change of permissions for admin repo?

Tags: gitolite

Is there a way how to prevent users, who I would like to be able to add repositories and modify permissions, from changing permissions of gitolite-admin?

Comment: Ok, I see the edit. Let me check. Check done. Answer edited.

Comment: So basically, you  *never* give access to gitolite.conf. Never. But with wild repos and delegation, you can give access to sub-configuration files in which a local admin can change any permission he/she wants, and Gitolite will piece back together the main gitolite.conf file when those sub-config files are pushed back to the gitolite-admin repo.

Answer (score 0):

The gitolite-admin repo is usually only `RW` by the gitolite admin account.

```
repo gitolite-admin
    RW+     =   gitoliteadm
```

Ie it isn't visible by any other users.
So they won't be able to clone that repo, and access the `gitolite.conf` file which would allow them to change permission on any repo.

---

#### Repos creation

Now, with [Gitolite V3](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/master-toc.html), you can authorize users to declare new repo and create them *without* giving them access to the gitolite-adm repo.
This is called "**[wild repo](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/wild.html)**".

> The wildrepos feature allows you to specify access control rules using regular expression patterns, so you can have many actual repos being served by a single set of rules in the config file.
>   **The regex pattern can also include the word CREATOR in it, allowing you to parametrize the name of the user creating the repo**.

```
@prof       =   u1
@TAs        =   u2 u3
@students   =   u4 u5 u6

repo    assignments/CREATOR/a[0-9][0-9]
    C   =   @students
    RW+ =   CREATOR
    RW  =   WRITERS @TAs
    R   =   READERS @prof
```

> **Note the "`C`" permission**.
>   **This is a standalone "`C`", which gives the named users the right to create a repo**.
>   This is not to be confused with the "`RWC`" or its variants described elsewhere, which are about *branches*, *not* repos.

---

#### Permission management

It is called **[delegation](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/deleg.html)**:

> Delegation allows you to divide up a large conf file into smaller groups of repos (called subconfs) and hand over responsibility to manage them to sub-admins.
>   Gitolite can prevent one sub-admin from being able to set access rules for any other sub-admin's repos.

Comment: The problem is that I would like them to be able to access ```gitolite.conf``` to add or change permissions to other repositories. (I have edited the question to clear that.)